# База данных csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, csv

У меня имеется csv бд с n количеством строк, как можно получить рандомные строки из нее с помощью python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```py
import csv
import random

def get_random_string(num):
    with open('test.txt') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        return random.sample(list(reader), k=num)
```

`num` - количество строк.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

def get_random_sample(sample_len: int):
    df = pd.read_csv('test.txt') # Чтение csv файла с помощью pandas
    return df.sample(n=sample_len)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]